# Write Csv with columns parsing wikipedia pages

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I'm trying to correct the code below, resultless, to write a fileout cvs with columns for every attribute of wikipedia page (t, s, u, li, i).

How can I change it to obtain a right output?

```
import csv
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang('it')
fileout=open('D:\\GIS\\Dati\\Vinca\\out.csv', 'w', encoding="utf8")
with open('D:\\GIS\\Dati\\Vinca\\specie_vinca_min.csv', 'rt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(fileout)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            wikipage = wikipedia.page(row[0], auto_suggest=False)
            t=wikipage.title
            s=wikipage.summary
            u=wikipage.url
            li=len(wikipage.images)
            i=wikipage.images[0]
            tot=t, s, u, li, i
            writer.writerow(tot)
        except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
        #if a "PageError" was raised, ignore it and continue to next link
            continue
            fileout.close()
            f.close()
```

The output isn't tabulated:
[image]

Comment: What issue are you seeing ? What is the error output ?

Comment: The output is not tabulated so I have problems to use it for my Gis work. Look the screenshot in question!

Comment: A CSV writer will use commas by default. Why do you think your code should write as "tabulated"?

Comment: The text in records contains commas so I can't use them to divide column. I tried to insert a "|" delimiter but It doesn't work. I'm beginner and I probably wrong some simple things.

Comment: Have you gone over the documentation for `csv.writer`? You can specify a column separator.

Comment: I think the problem is in the text of wikipage.summary. It contains wrap text. I try to use delimiter for csv.writer. It work when I use all the columns without  the summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Wikipedia.summary output contains many \n that created problems with columns.
Adding `st=s.replace('\n',' ')`,I removed the problem.
Now I have a table with right column.

```
import csv
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang('it')
fileout=open('D:\\GIS\\Dati\\Vinca\\out1.csv', 'w', encoding="utf8")
with open('D:\\GIS\\Dati\\Vinca\\specie_vinca_min.csv', 'rt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(fileout, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        try:
            wikipage = wikipedia.page(row[0], auto_suggest=False)
            t=wikipage.title
            s=wikipage.summary
            st=s.replace('\n',' ')
            u=wikipage.url
            li=len(wikipage.images)
            i=wikipage.images[0]
            tot= t,st,u, li, i
            writer.writerow(tot)
        except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
        #if a "PageError" was raised, ignore it and continue to next link
            continue
            fileout.close()
            f.close()
```